# Unable to perform the request. CFNetwork error: The request timed out

Tags: xcode, xcode-server

When trying to connect to Xcode Server on another mac from Xcode on Development Mac there is an error:

[image]

Do you know the reason of this? My administrator claims that everything is fine. Should I believe it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

- remove your Server from Xcode
- Quit Xcode
- Open Xcode
- Add Server again.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, your Xcode bots server stops running. Happened to me after updateing Xcode on our build server. As a result, I faced the exact same failure as posted in the original question.

**Solution:**

On your Mac where you run the Bots:

- Open XCode Preferences
- Open "Server & Bots"
- If it is "off", turn it "on"